# No sound from right speakers

Tags: 14.04, sound, speakers

I have Creative Sound Blaster Live 24-bit sound card and 5.1 surround speakers.

Front & rear left, center speakers are working but no sound from right speakers (both front and rear). There is no hardware problem and they work in Windows 7.

How can I solve this problem?

Edit: In *pavucontrol*, it's seen that system sound is **mono**. I think that this is the reason of my problem but how can this be solved?

[image: pavucontrol]

Comment: Did you look at the other tabs? Like Output devices? And try showing other devices with the dropdown.

Comment: Note that for more recent versions of ubuntu there may currently be a bug out there: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1672822 (click this also affects me if you think you are affected after reading trough, you may also add in your own details).

Answer (score 3):

Install the pavucontrol program like this:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

or reinstall *pavucontrol*. Worked for me.

Comment: I don't how this worked but it worked

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and fixed it in a strange way.

Go to alsamixer (just type `alsamixer` in terminal)

Make sure your sound card is the one selected by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> which will show you a list for the available sound cards. Select yours! ...If you're not sure try them all. It's not dangerous ;)

[image: alsamixer]

...I noticed that I had many volume bars having their right part lower than their left part. (in this picture you see only one). So I just lowered all their volumes to zero and back up again and they became even. *(to "navigate" just use your arrow keys. Right and left to select the bar, up and down to lower/raise the volume)*.

Hope it's your case too!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but found that it was due to the sound card.

When I had Windows & my Yamaha card did not work at all I bought Creative SB 5.1 which worked when the software was downloaded and installed.

When I switched over to Linux only the left speaker worked. I switched back to the Yamaha Sound card and everything was fine without any effort. So the sound card is likely to be the culprit.