# No sound from 5.1 speakers?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, speakers

I checked the suggested questions[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496607/no-sound-from-right-speakers) [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51801/no-sound-from-speakers) but they don't help.

I have a 5.1 speaker system. 2 satellite speakers (front+left) + the subwoofer are working, but none of the other 3 satellite speakers I plug in are receiving sound.

All of the satellite speakers plug into the subwoofer and it's a new system.

alsamixer shows [image]

But sound is only coming from 2 speakers (front left+right) and not the other 3.

I don't think all of the 3 speakers are not working.

How can I trouble fix this?

Edit: Additional info: Connected by motherboard speaker jack: Asus B350M-A

Speaker system is a Creative SBS-580

Xubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: We will need more details about your setup. How exactly are the speakers connected? Include in your question the make/model of each speaker, the make/model of the audio device you are using, and the details about every port and cable between your computer and each speaker. We need to know the type of each cable and the details about the ports they are connected to on each end. Have you made any changes to pulse audio configs? It so, please copy/paste your pulseaudio configs in the body of your question and use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) Tag me @Nmath or I'll miss it

Comment: Also include any other sound settings that you've configured, including sound system settings. You can upload a screenshot of the associated sound system settings.

Comment: Hello my speakers are connected using the green speaker jack on my motherboard (Asus B350M-A) The speaker system is a Creative SBS-580. I'm on Xubuntu 20.04.3. I haven't made any changes to my sound settings.

Answer (score 0):

If your speakers connect to your computer with a single 3.5 mm jack, then you need to change your settings to "Stereo" (2-channel).

The reason you must use stereo is because a single 3.5 mm jack can only carry 2 channels of uncompressed audio. While it can carry compressed streams like DTS and Dolby Digital, these compressed streams require a processor that can decrypt these streams on the receiving end.  This is a common feature of A/V receivers, but not speaker kits like the one you have.

If the speakers only have a single 3.5 mm jack to connect to your computer, then the speakers actually derive 5.1 channels from 2-channel audio.  A 5.1 speaker system with only a single 3.5 mm jack isn't capable of receiving 6 distinct channels.

Once you change your settings to stereo, you should be able to hear sound from all speakers. 5.1 channels should be derived from the two channel input.

Comment: Ok but which 'setting' in which interface? In Pulseaudio Volume control there's no such option?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Xfce but there should be configurable settings for sound under the desktop environment's system settings menu.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no such option, hence why I posted the question. Thanks anyway.